# SQLite 2 small tables vs one big

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'd like to optimize an app, kinda scheduler. I have tasks with different statuses like **done**, **to do** and **archived**(after delete). App logic uses the first two types the most, so should I keep them in the same table(and just selecting **done** & **to do** every time I need) or should I do a copy table just for archived items to make the select "easier" because status **archived** is very rarely used.

So does sqLite db size affects somehow db operations or not? I tested select operations in big tables(only one in whole db) and it take a long time to process 100K - 1M rows

Comment: Use one table. Index properly and that's it. Super fast, normalized and easy.

Comment: Answer It If you know that, I am also interested!! @juergend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has no problem with big tables and 1 millions records is not really big.

You should use only multiple tables if it makes sense logically, performance is not an issue. So your only table could look like this:

```
tasks table
---------------------------
id                    (primary key)
title                 (indexed)
description
status (or status_id) (indexed)
```

A rule of thumb is to index all columns you use in the `where` clauses of your queries.

If you use strings as `status` in your DB then you could use another table and refer to it in your `tasks` table with a foreign key to the `id` of this table:

```
status table
------------
id
name
```